# Sitemap Java code generator stopped working

Tags: sitemap

I have some java code to generate my sitemap. Suddenly stop working.

When I enter https://example.com/sitemap.xml it returns the sitemap unformatted, I guess because of that it's been rejected in Google Search Console.

It's a Spring Boot 2.0.5 RELEASE project.

SitemapController.java ==>

```
@Controller
public class SitemapController {

    @RequestMapping("/sitemap.xml")
    @ResponseBody
    public XmlUrlSet main() {

        XmlUrlSet xmlUrlSet = new XmlUrlSet();

        create(xmlUrlSet, "/", XmlUrl.Priority.HIGH);

        return xmlUrlSet;
    }

    private void create(XmlUrlSet xmlUrlSet, String link, XmlUrl.Priority priority) {
        xmlUrlSet.addUrl(new XmlUrl("https://example.com" + link, priority));
    }
}
```

XmlUrl.java ==>

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "url")
public class XmlUrl {
    public enum Priority {
        HIGH("1.0"), MEDIUM("0.5");

        private String value;

        Priority(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    @XmlElement
    private String loc;

    @XmlElement
    private String lastmod = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);

    @XmlElement
    private String changefreq = "daily";

    @XmlElement
    private String priority;

    public XmlUrl() {

    }

    public XmlUrl(String loc, Priority priority) {
        this.loc = loc;
        this.priority = priority.getValue();
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public String getChangefreq() {
        return changefreq;
    }

    public String getLastmod() {
        return lastmod;
    }
}
```

XmlUrlSet.java ==>

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "urlset", namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")
public class XmlUrlSet {

    @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "url", type = XmlUrl.class)})
    private Collection<XmlUrl> xmlUrls = new ArrayList<XmlUrl>();

    public void addUrl(XmlUrl xmlUrl) {
        xmlUrls.add(xmlUrl);
    }

    public Collection<XmlUrl> getXmlUrls() {
        return xmlUrls;
    }
}
```

package-info.java ==>

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", 
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package com.example.utility;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

I was expecting an output like this:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-09-29</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

But I'm getting some unformatted XML like this:

```
https://example.com/2019-07-09daily1.0
```

Please help!

Comment: I just realized this code works perfectly on Spring 1.5.6.RELEASE but not in 2.0.5 RELEASE. Anyone could help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! It needs to change the controller to put "produces" parameter, as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sitemap.xml", produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
```